# What is the best way to simulate keyboard button press in Python

Tags: python, keyboard, ctypes, keyboard-events, win32com

I've tried ctypes:

```
def a():
    SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_A))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    SendInput(Keyboard(KEY_A, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP))
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

and win32com.client SendKeys:

```
import win32com.client
import time

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")


def key_pause():
    time.sleep(0.03)


def a():
    shell.SendKeys("{a}", 0)
    key_pause()
```

and so far many programs still don't register them. Is there a way to simulate keyboard button press that will succeed every time in any program? I work on Windows 10.

Comment: pynput does this too apparently https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput